# SMS api not working on server but fine on localhost

Tags: php, api, curl, sms

This code is working fine on localhost, but not on server although it is generating password on server. `cURL` is enabled on my server and on localhost it is sending message fine.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        $adm=$_POST["admno"];
        $phn=$_POST["phn1"];
        include("model.php");
        $db = new database;
        $r=$db->register($adm);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r)){

            if($row["phn_no1"]==$phn  || $row["phn_no2"]==$phn  || $row["phn_no3"]==$phn)
            {
                $formatted = "".substr($phn,6,10)." ";
                $password = $formatted + $adm;
                echo $password;
                $db->setpassword($adm,$password);
                $pre = 'Dear%20Parents,Your%20Password%20is%20';
                $suf = '%20ThankYou.CV';
                $sms = $pre.$password.$suf;

                $ch = curl_init("http://www.perfectbulksms.in/Sendsmsapi.aspx?USERID=ID&PASSWORD=PASS$&SENDERID=SID&TO=$phn&MESSAGE=$sms");
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
                header("Location:password.php?msg=new"); 

            } else {
                header("Location:register.php?msg=invalid");    
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: any errors on the server? checked the error logs?

Comment: Make sure you have cURL installed on your server and server allows external API calls.

Comment: yes i checked that curl is enabled but how to check that my server allows external api calls or not... when i only sends message using this api in new header it is working fine but only in curl command it is not working.... but i want to use two header location ... Is there any alternate of this and i also want to hide my api